# Plotting with interpolation using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

**Program description:**

> You are given a set of two functions: $$f=x^3-6x^2+x+5; g=(x-2)^2-6$$
> Plot them using Matprolib on a user input segment [a; b].

**My solution:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interpolate # for smoothing

def func(x):
    return [pow(x, 3) - 6 * pow(x, 2) + x + 5, pow((x-2), 2) - 6]
# plt.plot([1,5, -3, 0.5], [1, 25, 9, 0.5])
# plt.plot(1, 7, "r+")
# plt.plot(-1, 7, "bo")
f = []
f_1 = []
x = []
interval = [int(x) for x in input("Define segment (i.e. a b): ").split(' ')]
for val in range(interval[0], interval[1] + 1):
    x.append(val)
    f.append(func(val)[0])
    f_1.append(func(val)[1])

linear_space = np.linspace(interval[0], interval[1], 300)
a_BSpline = interpolate.make_interp_spline(x, f)
b_BSpline = interpolate.make_interp_spline(x, f_1)

f_new = a_BSpline(linear_space)
f_1_new = b_BSpline(linear_space)

plt.plot(linear_space, f_new, color="#47c984",
linestyle="solid", linewidth=1)

plt.plot(linear_space, f_1_new, color="#fc6703",
linestyle="solid", linewidth=1)

plt.gca().spines["left"].set_position("zero")
plt.gca().spines["bottom"].set_position("zero")
plt.show()
```

**Input:** `-10 10`

**Output:**

[image: 1]

**Question:**
Is there any way to make this code more concise?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need `interpolate.make_interp_spline`? If it is required, please update the problem statement and title to include the corresponding logic.

Comment: @GZ0 when importing interpolate I've intentionally left a comment that it is going to be used for smoothing, thank you for the tip though, I've updated the title accordingly,

Comment: The logic does not sound right to me. The problem begins with two polynominal functions, which are smooth, rather than piecewise functions which are non-smooth at interval boundaries. Why is it necessary to compute another two sets of smoothing coefficients?

Comment: @GZ0 interpolation is used for style purposes only, otherwise functions' graphs look rough. Interval boudaries are given on user input, I don't quite get you here. The problem is simple, just plot two functions. I've provided necessary **input** and **output** in my question.

Comment: @GZ0 sorry, you are right, I have left the part about custom segment out, I've edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As I pointed out in the comments, I do not think smoothing is needed when plotting functions that are already smooth, such as polynominals. In those cases, the graphs would look rough only if the points plotted are not dense enough (on the x axis).
- Since you have already imported and used `numpy`, it would be better to use [`numpy.polyval`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html#numpy.polyval) for vectorized evaluation of polynominals.
- Drawing spines at zero would not work well if the input range does not include zero. In that case, the `"center"` position might be used instead of `"zero"`. (I will not implement this logic in my code below)
- The top and right spines should not be shown.
- Consider using `plt.style.use` for setting common style information. See [here](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#defining-your-own-style) for alternative options for style setting.
- Avoid constants like `"#47c984"`. Name them with appropriate constant names for better readability.
- It is a good practice to comply to the [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style when writing Python code. Use an IDE (such as PyCharm) or an online checker (such as [this](http://pep8online.com/)) for automatic PEP 8 violation checking.
- When running code outside a method / class, it is a good practice to put the code inside a *main guard*. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) for more explanation.

Here is an improved version:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Define constants (color names come from https://colornamer.robertcooper.me/)
    INPUT_MESSAGE = "Lower and upper bounds of x, separated by a space: "
    NUM_POINTS = 300
    PARIS_GREEN = "#47c984"
    BLAZE_ORANGE = "#fc6703"

    # Read input
    lb, ub = map(float, input(INPUT_MESSAGE).split())

    # Compute coordinates of points to be plotted
    x = np.linspace(lb, ub, NUM_POINTS)
    f_x = np.polyval([1, -6, 1, 5], x)
    g_x = np.square(x - 2) - 6

    # Plotting
    plt.style.use({"lines.linestyle": "solid", "lines.linewidth": 1})
    plt.plot(x, f_x, color=PARIS_GREEN)
    plt.plot(x, g_x, color=BLAZE_ORANGE)

    # Adjust spines
    spines = plt.gca().spines
    spines["left"].set_position("zero")
    spines["bottom"].set_position("zero")
    spines["right"].set_visible(False)
    spines["top"].set_visible(False)

    # Display plot
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. Why don't you consider spines to be const?

Comment: Using a constant would be the same as using 0. The coordinates have to vary based on the input range. `"center"` is just a convenient way to achieve that.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you again.

Comment: By the way, @GZ0, g(x) is not displayed correctly, it's displayed as a plain line.

Comment: Its should be displayed like this: http://yotx.ru/#!1/3_h/ubWwf7Wwf7Rgzhf23/aP9g/2DfT0qt7W/sbe7sru9snu4f7JNo2I2dU8bj6RbjcevyYnd/ax8D

Comment: `g(x)` is correct. It looks like a line only because of the scale of the y axis. There is a bug in the code and it is fixed in my updated answer.

Comment: I don't understand your changes, as the plotting didn't change. Values at Y axis were still 10 times larger than those that were on the X axis. I've fixed the problem manually by leaving `plt.ylim(lb, ub)`

Comment: @JoshJohnson The scale of the y axis is determined by `f(x)` in this case since it dominates the y range and shares the axis with `g(x)` in the plot.